# opencv undefined reference to imread with CMake on windows10 VS Code

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, cmake, visual-studio-code

I want to run OpenCV on VS Code IDE with CMake, but it shows `undefined reference to cv::imread()`. I've tried several ways (e.g edit PATH variables...) to solve the problem, however it still can link to the opencv library.

- Here is my `CMakelists.txt`

  ```
  # cmake needs this line
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

  # Enable C++11
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)

  # Define project name
  project(cvtest)

  # Find OpenCV, you may need to set OpenCV_DIR variable
  # to the absolute path to the directory containing OpenCVConfig.cmake file
  # via the command line or GUI
  find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

  set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/opencv/build/include")
  include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

  # If the package has been found, several variables will
  # be set, you can find the full list with descriptions
  # in the OpenCVConfig.cmake file.
  # Print some message showing some of them
  message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
  message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
  message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
  message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

  # Declare the executable target built from your sources
  add_executable(cvtest cvtest.cpp)

  # Link your application with OpenCV libraries
  target_link_libraries(cvtest ${OpenCV_LIBS})
  ```
- After finishing CMake settings, I run `$ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"`.

  ```
  -- OpenCV library status:
  --     version: 2.4.13.6
  --     libraries: opencv_videostab;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_photo;opencv_ocl;opencv_objdetect;opencv_nonfree;opencv_ml;opencv_legacy;opencv_imgproc;opencv_highgui;opencv_gpu;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_core;opencv_contrib;opencv_calib3d
  --     include path: C:/opencv/build/include
  ```
- At last, I run **`$ mingw32-make`**, but it came out with some errors

  ```
  Scanning dependencies of target cvtest
  [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cvtest.dir/cvtest.cpp.obj
  [100%] Linking CXX executable cvtest.exe
  CMakeFiles\cvtest.dir/objects.a(cvtest.cpp.obj):cvtest.cpp:(.text+0x63): 
  undefined reference to cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
  CMakeFiles\cvtest.dir/objects.a(cvtest.cpp.obj):cvtest.cpp:(.text+0x87): 
  undefined reference to cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
  CMakeFiles\cvtest.dir/objects.a(cvtest.cpp.obj):cvtest.cpp:(.text+0xc1): 
  undefined reference to cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
  c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
  CMakeFiles\cvtest.dir/objects.a(cvtest.cpp.obj): bad reloc address 0xf in section `.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[__ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]'
  c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
  final link failed: Invalid operation
  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  CMakeFiles\cvtest.dir\build.make:104: recipe for target 'cvtest.exe' failed
  mingw32-make[2]: *** [cvtest.exe] Error 1
  CMakeFiles\Makefile2:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cvtest.dir/all' failed
  mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cvtest.dir/all] Error 2
  Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
  mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
  ```
- Here is `cvtest.cpp`

  ```
  #include <cstdio>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

  using namespace cv;
  using namespace std;

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      Mat img = imread("lena.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
      imshow("lena", img);
  }
  ```

---

Did I misunderstanding something I should know and how can I correct it ? Thanks !

Comment: You have `message()` calls in your `CMakeLists.txt`. Add their output into the question post - this information would be very useful. Also, why do you set `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable manually? This variable is set by `find_package(OpenCV)` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for reply ! I've add output to the post. I set `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` manually in order to correctly include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>. Otherwise, it will catch the wrong path...

Comment: Project is correct, problem must be in your environment (but I don't work on Windows, so hard to tell what exactly). If you say that `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` is not set correctly (don't set it by hand!), your opencv installation must be broken. Try to install it again following official docs.

Comment: @Ptaq666 thanks for reply! I've solved the problem today. The problem is due to that I didn't compile/build opencv library with `MinGW` compiler. After using cmake-gui and cmd to build library, just like you guys said , `find_package(OpenCV)` gives the right path, and the project is running successfully.  Maybe I will write some notes for what mistake I've made and how I solved the problem. Thanks you guys ~

Comment: @Ryspon If you resolved the issue, please consider writing an Answer post for your question. This way, others can easily see how you solved the problem and learn from it.